# Select malformed URLs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to select users where their Internet website URL is malformed.

I need to:

1. not select empty "Internet" fields
2. select "Internet" fields where the URL is malformed.

I have entered one malformed URL - www.te st.com - with a space in between, that I use to test. I tried this query but the result list is blank.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM calendario 
WHERE `Internet` NOT REGEXP '^(https?:\/\/|www\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}' AND `Internet` !='' ORDER BY Data DESC";
```

Does anyone know what I do wrong with MySQL URL validation?

Comment: The PHP is erring or no rows are matched? Also note a backslash in a character class in posix doesn't escape, but `.`s dont need to be escaped and the `-` as the last character should be correct.

Comment: there are top level extensions out there that don't fit in this range `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` https://www.key-systems.net/en/blog/list-of-domain-extensions

Answer (score 1):

`.` as meta-character should be escaped with double quote `\\.` or placed into a character class `[.]`

The following query should work as expected:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM calendario 
WHERE `Internet` NOT REGEXP '^(https?:\/\/|www\\.)[-.A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}' 
    AND `Internet` !='' ORDER BY Data DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.